# XHTML-radio button: what's the 'false' value?

Tags: html, radio-button, xhtml

I just tried the following HTML :

```
<input type='radio' checked='checked' name='test' id='r1' />
<input type='radio' checked='' name='test' id='r2' />
```

which (in my mind's eye) should have the first radio button checked.  Turns out browsers will check any radio button with a `checked` attribute.

Is there a 'false' value, that won't check the button, so my code is consistent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The absence of the checked attribute is the only way you can do this.

Traditionally only the word checked was requried to indicate a checked status (you didn't have to set it to be a value). I think the attributename="value" pattern is for compatibility with standards such as xhtml (which is why browsers ignore the value itself)

Comment: Yes, `<input checked />` looks sloppy and inconsistent.  Ah well can't have everything.  Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: The attributename="attributename" form for boolean attributes was part of HTML 2.0 (http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1866.txt) - long before XHTML was invented.

Answer (score 2):

The presence of the `checked` attribute is generally enough for the browser to have it checked by default.

In a radio control group though, I'd just put the attribute on the initial one selected and omit it on the other radio elements.

Answer (score 1):

There's no false value. If the checkbox is not checked, the browser will not send it via $_GET or $_POST. You should use "value" attribute also - and check on serverside for that value. Otherwise it's false.